# Html5 CSS Layout Footer

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a sticky footer but I'm getting empty space above and below my header & footer.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
footer {
  background-color: #202020;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Porfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>header</h1>
    <p>header</p>
  </header>

  <div class="wrapper">
    content
  </div>

  <footer>
    footer
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

What is the best way to create a sticky footer?
Can anyone explain why I've got this space appearing above header & below footer when I have content (h1 p) in in my header section.

Comment: I like the method used [in this blog post](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) the best. It's mobile and desktop safe. He explains it better than I could so just offering the resource.

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

For the header gap, your `h1` and `p` tags have a default padding and margin, you may want to remove them or reduce them to your liking

```
h1, p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h1,p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
footer {
  background-color: #202020;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Porfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>header</h1>
    <p>header</p>
  </header>

  <div class="wrapper">
    content
  </div>

  <footer>
    footer
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please, mark as answer so the next person needing an answer will know.

Answer (score 0):

A "sticky" div can be achieved using `position: fixed;` in your footer CSS. Fixed means that the on-screen position will never change. Or rather you should [follow the instructions posted there](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/).

Concerning the space, it is probably because of the default styles applied to `h1`. Use a debugger to see those default styles and override them with your custom css.

Firefox and Chrome have built in debuggers that also let you view styles and are very efficient for debugging. Usually right click > "inspect element" then go for the CSS tab which lets your select and see styles applied to elements.

Comment: If desktop only, then I would go with fixed positioning; however, iOS has problems rendering fixed positioning at times.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are not "resetting" the `h1` and `p` tags. By default these elements have some extra margin.

Try adding the following code to your css.

```
h1, p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Also check out the [HTML5 CSS Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/).

Answer (score 0):

you may use flex prperties

`.wrapper` may scroll,  `header` & `footer` are sticky

```css
/* demo purpose */
.wrapper:hover:before {
  content:'test';
  display:block;
  height:1000px;
  }
/* end demo purpose*/
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
}
header {
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
footer {
  background-color: #202020;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  flex:1;
  overflow:auto;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Porfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>header</h1>
    <p>header</p>
  </header>

  <div class="wrapper">
    content
  </div>

  <footer>
    footer
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

or just `footer` is sticky ?, *needs an extra imbrication*

```css
/* demo purpose */
.wrapper:hover:before {
  content:'test';
  display:block;
  height:1000px;
  }
/* end demo purpose*/html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body, main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
header {
  background-color: orange;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}
footer {
  background-color: #202020;
  color: white;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.wrapper, main {
  flex: 1;
  }
main {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Porfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <header>
      <h1>header</h1>
      <p>header</p>
    </header>

    <div class="wrapper">
      content
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    footer
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
footer {
  background-color: #202020;
  color: white;
  //replace absolute with fixed for sticky footer (as in, it sticks at the bottom.)
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

I saw this comment you posted on another answer:

If desktop only, then I would go with fixed positioning; however, iOS has problems rendering fixed positioning at times. – SergeantHacker

Try removing height 100% from body and html.